# Sorting a column with boolean values which are grouped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `df` which is grouped and count of boolean in each group.

I want to sort the 'occurrence'  in descending order while remaining grouped by state and booleans

```
property_state  delinquency    occurrence
AK              False          119
                True            17
AL              False          928
                True           185
AR              False          500
                              ... 
WI              True           432
WV              False          177
                True            26
WY              False          140
                True            34
```

I have tried:

```
df.sort_values(df['occurrence'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
```

and:

```
df = df.sort_values('occurrence').groupby('state')
```

but i get

> <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000022AB4B51DC8>

Comment: Post your df so we can better help

Answer (score 0):

This `df = df.sort_values('occurrence').groupby('state')` is correct and just if need goup by both`state` and `delinquency`change it to:

`df = df.sort_values('occurrence').groupby(['state','delinquency'])`

But now in the new df you have a grouped df, so you must decide what are you going to do with this grouping. If you just want to make it just ordered then just use:

`df.reset_index()`

Thus my final answer is:

```
df = df.sort_values('occurrence').groupby(['state','delinquency'])
df = df.reset_index()
```

or

```
df = df.sort_values('occurrence').groupby(['state','delinquency']).reset_index()
```